How to create ASP.NET Core Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU) with WebRTC?
I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core SFU, to which users can connect and stream video (maybe also audio) both ways. In the future I also have to implement recording of the streams.
After some research I decided to go with WebRTC.
Unfortunately, I am bound to using .NET and that is kind of a problem, because I found a few libraries and products such as Livekit which I think would do what I need. But I did not find any C# implementation of their SDK. Is there any library or product which would be useful?
Only thing I found that could be used in .NET is SIPSorcery which allows to work with WebRTC.
If I decide to use SIPSorcery WebRTC do I need to work with the RTP packets and forward them or is it possible to somehow add another user's stream to the new PeerConnection with other user?
Thank you for any help!

Based on my research you are right that there are few tools can be used for .net . It is still under heavy development. It is possible to add another user's stream to the new PeerConnection with other user but meaningless as you may need to implement it manually, which is contrary to the intention of SFU with WebRTC. For some further usage you could consider WebSocket for the interaction.

@FengzhiZhou Thank you for response. So if I understand it correctly there are two options. First is to make it using WebRTC and SIPSorcery for example and handle RTP packets manually. And second option is to make it using WebSockets? Would there be any challenges if implementing using WebSockets (maybe NAT traversal)?

Yes WebSocket has many challenges as it does not have a good scalability for this issue. It is better to implement WebRTC and SIPSorcery and consider WebSocket as an alternative only.
